# Lorentz transform in Unruh effect

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, fourier-transform, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

I'm re-reading about the Unruh effect and while I broadly understand the concept of plugging through the coordinate transform and the Bogoliubov transformation, I'm curious as to whether there is a slightly more intuitive, at least in the maths sense, way to get at this.

For example, any Lorentz boost doesn't give rise to this effect, and so it seems reasonable that any linear transformation of the coordinates, i.e. $t' = t \gamma + \lambda$, something similar for $x'$, wouldn't give rise to this effect.

Is there some general argument about how Fourier coefficients transform under nonlinear transformations that can be applied here which would explain why the annihilation operator in one frame needs to be expressed as sums of both sets of coefficients/operators in the other frame?

Comment: I think intuitively, you can imagine that a strong electric field applied to the vacuum would excite electron positron pairs.  Do you have the proof somewhere, I remember seeing it but I can't imagine how to do it or explain it intuitively with out it lol